# Use pedestal in usual http way request-response

Tags: clojure, cordova, pedestal

I'm newbie in pedestal, please advise.

AFAIK, pedestal is service + js application (browser based). Communication through keep alive  connection (long), render on client side.

Is it possible to use pedestal in the usual web way - request-response?
Can libraries like Hiccup or Enlive be used?

And is it possible to have iPhone application via PhoneGap? Maybe someone has had previous experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is two questions in one post.

Comment: Pedestal has dropped the app-side. Please see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pedestal-users/jODwmJUIUcg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use Pedestal in Request/Respons  applications. I highly recommend that you check the sample application provided by Pedestal.io team:

https://github.com/pedestal/samples/blob/master/template-server/src/template_server/service.clj

and [Pedestal App Tutorial](https://github.com/pedestal/app-tutorial).

Comment: Maybe you can advise screencasts or presentations as well? Thanks!

Comment: Thats is why we have Google! :)

Comment: yep :) but i didnt find any usefull. Thanks anyway.